# How to solve the primal problem via Lagrangian directly?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, duality-theorems

From section 5.5.5 of Convex Optimization by Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenberghe [https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), consider the primal problem
$$\begin{cases}
\min:\ f_0(x)\\
\mathrm{s.t.\ }f_i(x)\leq 0,i=1,\dots,m; h_i(x)=0,i=1,\dots,p.
\end{cases}$$
The book in page 248 of section 5.5.5 says that "Suppose we have strong duality and an optimal $(\lambda^{\star}, \nu^{\star})$ is known. Suppose that the minimizer of Lagrangian $L(x, \lambda^{\star}, \nu^{\star})$, i.e., the solution of
$${\min}:f_0(x) + \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i^{\star}f_i(x) + \sum_{i=1}^p \nu_i^{\star} h_i(x)\ \ \tag{5.55}$$
is unique.
Then if the solution of (5.55) is primal feasible, it must be primal optimal.

I am confused about why the solution of (5.55) is the primal optimal if it is unique and feasible.

Comment: It is not clear to me either.

Comment: I am not inclined to believe this result, albeit I am unable to produce a counterexample. I think it needs some form of complimentary slackness.

Comment: Try having a look at KKT conditions. It might help.

Comment: I think we may need the complimentary slackness condition in KKT. But this is hard to prove.

Comment: Some smoothness conditions and/or constraint qualification would be needed. However, the book should clarify that as it is far from clear.

Answer (score 3):

**This is a counterexample.** Set
\begin{align*}
f(x) &:= x^2 \exp(-x^2) - (x-1) \exp(x)\\
g(x) &:= f_1(x) := (x-1) \exp(x).
\end{align*}

For the primal problem, the feasible set is $(-\infty, 1]$ and the infimal value $0$ is not achieved (consider $x \to -\infty$).

The Lagrangian is $L(x,\lambda) := f(x) + \lambda g(x)$.
For $\lambda^* = 1$, we have
$$
L(x,\lambda^*) = x^2 \exp(-x^2)$$
and this function has a unique minimizer at $x_0 := 0$ with $L(x_0,\lambda^*) = 0$.
Via weak duality, $\lambda^*$ is a dual solution.
(Actually, it can be checked that this dual solution is also unique.)
Since the primal and dual optimal values coincide, we have strong duality.
Note that $x_0$ is feasible (but complementary slackness is violated).

One should also note that all functions are smooth
and at the boundary point $x = 1$, $g'(x) \ne 0$, i.e., a CQ is satisfied.

**What can be shown?** If we add the assumption of complementary slackness, i.e.,
$f_i(x_0) \lambda^*_i = 0$ for all $i$, then the assertion of the book holds, but we can drop uniqueness and strong duality:
Let $(\lambda^*, \mu^*)$ be dual optimal and let $x_0$ be a(!) solution of (5.55), which is primal feasible and satisfies strict complementarity.
Let $p^*$, $d^*$ be the optimal objective value of the primal and dual program, respectively. We have
$$
p^* \ge d^* = L(x_0, \lambda^*, \mu^*) = f(x_0).$$
Here, the identities are:

- weak duality,
- optimality of $(\lambda^*, \mu^*)$ and definition of $x_0$,
- strict complementarity.

Hence, $x_0$ is primal optimal.

Comment: +1 Very nice. ${}{}$